# Is there any function in OpenCV or Emgu CV desktop capture options? (addons, libs, classes)

Tags: opencv, desktop, capture, emgucv

Is there any function in OpenCV or Emgu CV desktop capture options? (addons, libs, classes) So I know we can capture camera in a very easy way, is there any option for desktop capturing that way?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this and use Emgu CV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing a screen capture outside of Emgu (ie, in non-Emgu C++/C#).

The first step is to create a bitmap from the screen image. There are plenty of websites detailing methods of how to do this. I found [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/cscapturescreen1.aspx) helpful.

Once you have a bitmap, it's easy to create new Emgu Image<,> from it. Here's [the documentation for that](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Creating_image_from_Bitmap).

Good luck, and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This solution is also one outside of emgucv: you can also use the c sharp **System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen**

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
```